# Regex (Has between 1 and 4 digits and as many characters as possible)

Tags: regex

Hi trying to create a regex that ensures you have between 1 and 4 number of digits and also as many characters as possible

Here's what I have written so far `^([A-Za-z]+([0-9]){1,4}$)`

This doesnt allow me to have characters after the digits

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here. Can you show examples of strings you want to accept and examples of strings you want to reject? Did you really want to capture to the end of the input strings with the `$` at the end? What's allowed and not allowed after the 1-4 digits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might repeat the whole part 1-4 times and match optional trailing chars a-z

```
^(?:[A-Za-z]*[0-9]){1,4}[A-Za-z]*$
```

The pattern matches

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[A-Za-z]*[0-9]){1,4}` Repeat matching 1-4 times optionalchars a-z and a single digit
- `[A-Za-z]*` Optionally repeat char A-Za-z
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kzQcPd/1)

Comment: This looks great but doesn't allow consecutive numbers

Comment: @Benjamin I have updated the answer to match optional chars A-Za-z allowing consecutive numbers.